# How to add holidays to holidays class?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the Holidays gem and want to add some other holidays like this:

```
20.times do |i|
    year = ("20" + "%02d" % i).to_i
    [[year,1,1], [year,1,2], [year,1,3], [year,12,31]].map do |d|
        # add date to holidays
        {date: Date.new(d), name: "New Year's Week", regions: [:jp]}
    end
end
```

I don't know how to set new holidays to a Holidays class. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option would be to fork this gem on github and add your own holidays in YAML files of your own fork.

And later install the gem from your own github repo, in bundler:

```
gem 'holidays', :git => 'https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays.git'
```

Of course change "alexdunae" to your own username ;)

Comment: I think an even better solution would be to fork it, and add the ability to load additional YAML files from a different disk location, and merge those into the appropriate region data, then submit that as a patch.